# Can i exactly set distance between div and div with text?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Suppose, I have two div's: first - rectangle, filled yellow color and second with text "World wide web" and font-size 46px. I need set distance 39px between bottom of first div and top of the capital letter "W" in second div. I set margin bottom 39px in first div's CSS rule, and measure result on the screen. I got 43px. Can I exactly set this distance? (of cource, I can tune margin of first div and  make several attempts to set this distance, but I need another way). Sorry for my English.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      test page
    </title>
    <style>
      html {
        line-height: 1;
      }
      #first {
        background-color: yellow;
        height: 200px;
        margin-bottom: 39px;
        width: 200px;  

      }

      #second {
        font-family: "Myriad Pro";
        font-size: 46px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id = "first">
     </div>
    <div id = "second">
      World wide web
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Check default browser styles that are being applied. Using something like [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) sometimes takes the guesswork out of why something is behaving this way or that way. Etc etc

Comment: I think, this is because font-size bigger than height of capital letter....

Comment: I include normalize.css and got the same result: 43px.

Comment: Your idea is correct: the X-height is not the same as the font size. You could compute what the X-height is, but I say, don't bother. Not all computers have the font Myriad Pro, so it will come out differently anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the space is part of the font. The size of second `div`, `font-size` and `line-height` all are `46px`. Also, the space between them is also `39px` as you can see [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/55f5j/show/). So, if you want to set the space to be exactly 39px, you might have to search for or make a font which doesn't has that extra space.

**OR**

you can set `line-height: 30px;` in second div, which will move it upward. But as value depends on font-size, you will have to change it whenever you change `font-size`. Maybe using `em`s can solve that issue

**EDIT**

Values in `em` would be:

```
font-size: 2.87em;
line-height: 0.655em;
```

Now changing `font-size` in em to any value will keep the gap to `39px`, i.e. `margin-bottom` of `div#first`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/55f5j/1/show/)

Comment: Can I compute size of this space? May be I need solve any equation to find size? Or it's impossible?

Comment: Which space? The extra space in font or the space between 2 divs? The space between `div`s would be same as the `margin-bottom`. Unfortunately I have no idea how to get extra space in font. It depends on `font-size` so its not static but changes when `font-size` changes

Comment: The extra space in font. What relation between font family, font size, and extra space in font?

Comment: Lets see, for `font-size: 2.87em` `line-height:0.66em` was able to get rid of all extra space, so space must be `1em-.66em` as 1em is normal line height. So, extra space is `0.34em`. So `34%` extra space, maybe? If I understand `em`s properly then this must be it. But there's no relation for `font-family`. I've seen fonts with about `70%` extra space!! I hate those fonts :P. BTW I am curious, why do you need such type of pixel perfection? Whats so special about `39px`?

Comment: Nothing special about 39px, it's only example from my experiments.I'm newbie in CSS and want understand it in details:) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might need to set the padding of the text in the second `div` to `{padding: 0}`.  Any padding that you have not accounted for will increase the appearance of the margin.  Have you tried adding a `background-color` to `#second` and then measuring the margin?

Comment: I can't see any padding on second div

Comment: I set background-color and get about 4px diff between top of the 'W' letter and border of #second. Padding 0 don't help. It's because font-size is bigger than capital letters. But how compute this difference without set background-colors, adjusting margins ... etc..?

Comment: In that case, you could set negative padding so that the containing div (with `padding: -4px`) will actually stop at the top of capital letters.

Comment: @MrLister wow I'm dumb.  Disregard negative padding comment.  What I _meant_ was to just set the margin 4px less than desired.  So in OP case, `margin-bottom: 35px`.  Negative padding.... SMH